# Persisted entity isn't retrieved by query until commit

Tags: caching, jpa, ejb

I am using a stateful session bean w/ an EXTENDED persistence context, and the following @TransactionAttribute settings:

```
@Stateful(...)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public class StatefulExtendedEJBBea {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "JPAModel", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager em;

    ...

    /**
     * With the REQUIRED txn attribute, we can ensure that each time
     * this method is called a new transaction is created and any
     * pending changes in the persistence context are committed.
     */
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void commitTransaction() {
    }

    /** <code>select o from Departments o</code> */
    public List<Departments> getDepartmentsFindAll() {
        return em.createNamedQuery("Departments.findAll").getResultList();
    }

    public <T> T persistEntity(T entity) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    }
 }
```

Some important things to call out in this example:

1. A txn is not begun when the persistEntity() method is called,
   because of the bean-level @TransactionAttribute(NOT_SUPPORTED)
   setting.
2. A txn is only begun, and completed, when the
   commitTransaction() method is called, because it is annotated
   @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRED).

This approach allows new entities to be persisted (and their IDs generated and auto-assigned by JPA, using @GeneratedValue) without JPA eagerly issuing an INSERT stmt in the DB.  Consequently, I can persist the entity right away, before assigning any property values, because NOT NULL column constraints are not yet validated.  Only when the commitTransaction() method is called does JPA perform the INSERT stmt and execute the COMMIT.

Now, that much appears to be working as I anticipated, with the benefits listed above.  The problem I'm having is I am unable to retrieve newly persisted entities through the JPQL query until after commitTransaction() is called.  Newly persisted entities appear to be managed by the persistence context, because I can continue to update them after calling persistEntity(), and all subsequent changes are properly saved into the DB when I call commitTransaction().  However, they doesn't appear to be in the query cache until I issue the commit.

I am guessing that my strategy of suppressing the txn until commit time is affecting the query results somehow.

Is there a query hint I can use to force persisted (outside of a transaction), but uncommitted, entities to be included in JPQL queries?

TIA

Comment: Queries always go to the database. If your entities are not in the database, they won't be found by your query.

Comment: Ok, so when JPA executes a JPQL stmt, it issues a preliminary query to retrieve only the PK values?  Then it iterates over those PK values, finds any entities in its cache that match, and only issues a full query with the where clause is the list of PKs that weren't found?

Comment: That's more or less what happens when you have a second-level cache and a query cache, with Hibernate (don't know for other implementations). But I don't see what it has to do with your question.

Comment: BTW, I appreciate your replies.  I asked because it explains why it won't find my pending (persisted but not yet INSERTed) entities.  I guess it is asking too much of JPA to figure out whether any such pending entities match the query results, and include them if so.

Answer (score 2):

You can call flush() to write changes to the database before commit.

See, http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Persisting#Flush

There is also a flush-mode on the EntityManager that will trigger a flush before each query, this defaults to auto, so it is odd you don't see the new objects.  Perhaps you are using a different transaction for the query?  In this case a different transaction will never see the uncommitted changes of another transaction, that kind of the point of a transaction.