# Hibernate / JPA how to getOrCreate(entity) and make get return uncommitted saved entities

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

If you are parsing a large **csv** file containing **many rows**, each row containing a **Product**.

You wish to populate all of file contents in **one transaction** using Hibernate / JPA. If one fails, then **all fails**.

However, I am trying to also keep track if a past Product has already been created in the past.

This creates a tiny issue for duplicate Descriptions for instance.

As an example, I create an entity, Description using getOrCreate(text, language). If it is not found, then create it, otherwise return the found one.

In one csv file, there seems to be **several descriptions** matching several **rows/Products**, with the same description for 2+ products.

This means that within one and same transaction, there are duplicates for the Description portion.

However, since the Transaction **is not yet committed**, findByLanguageAndText will/is not returning the past saved but uncommitted entity.

Is there a way to save in such a way that it remains as part of the transaction, or allow hibernate / jpa to return the previously saved Description entity but that has yet to be committed?

If I commit, can can I rollback in case of error later?

I can store these uncommitted stuff in a hashmap but this would create tremendous complexity.

What is the proposed best way to tackle this.

Comment: The entites don't need to be commited, a flush would be enough, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504934/persisted-entity-isnt-retrieved-by-query-until-commit

Comment: Under the perfomance aspect it could be the best to sort the csv in order of the description, so you only need to remember the last record

Comment: @Turo seems not to work though. They are not found.

Comment: @Turo thanks for clarifiying. Seems i had another issue with my query.